# PyQt: Hide a special column in QTreeView

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

I am just about to analyze the following executable code. Well, I want to hide a special column of QTreeView. In this case I read the documentation of Qt, and there I found the `setColumnHidden()-method`. Qt says:

> If hide is true the given column will be hidden

Please take a look into the `Window()-class`. You see I will try to hide first column from `self.proxyView`, **BUT** it also still visible. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# This is only needed for Python v2 but is harmless for Python v3.
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MySortFilterProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel.__init__(self, parent)
        #super(MySortFilterProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.minDate = QtCore.QDate()
        self.maxDate = QtCore.QDate()

    def setFilterMinimumDate(self, date):
        self.minDate = date
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterMinimumDate(self):
        return self.minDate

    def setFilterMaximumDate(self, date):
        self.maxDate = date
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterMaximumDate(self):
        return self.maxDate

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):

        #print "filterAcceptsRow is called"
        #print "sourceRow", sourceRow
        #print "sourceParent", sourceParent

        index0 = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent)
        index1 = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 1, sourceParent)
        index2 = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 2, sourceParent)

        return (   (self.filterRegExp().indexIn(str(self.sourceModel().data(index0))) >= 0
                    or self.filterRegExp().indexIn(self.sourceModel().data(index1)) >= 0)
                and self.dateInRange(self.sourceModel().data(index2)))

    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        leftData = self.sourceModel().data(left)
        rightData = self.sourceModel().data(right)

        if not isinstance(leftData, QtCore.QDate):
            emailPattern = QtCore.QRegExp("([\\w\\.]*@[\\w\\.]*)")

            if left.column() == 1 and emailPattern.indexIn(leftData) != -1:
                leftData = emailPattern.cap(1)

            if right.column() == 1 and emailPattern.indexIn(rightData) != -1:
                rightData = emailPattern.cap(1)

        return leftData < rightData

    def dateInRange(self, date):
        if isinstance(date, QtCore.QDateTime):
            date = date.date()

        return (    (not self.minDate.isValid() or date >= self.minDate)
                and (not self.maxDate.isValid() or date <= self.maxDate))


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.proxyModel = MySortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 3, self)

        self.filterPatternLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.filterPatternLineEdit.setText("Grace|Sports")

        self.filterPatternLineEdit.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.filter_update(string_text=self.filterPatternLineEdit.text(),
                                                                                  model=self.proxyModel))



        self.proxyView = QtGui.QTreeView()

        self.proxyView.setColumnHidden(0, True)
        self.proxyView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.proxyView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.proxyView.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.proxyView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.proxyView.sortByColumn(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)


        proxyLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.proxyView, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.filterPatternLineEdit, 1, 1)
        proxyGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox("Sorted/Filtered Model")
        proxyGroupBox.setLayout(proxyLayout)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        mainLayout.addWidget(proxyGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Custom Sort/Filter Model")
        self.resize(500, 450)

        self.createMailModel()
        self.setSourceModel(self.model)

    def setSourceModel(self, model):
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(model)

    def filter_update(self, string_text=None, model=None):

        syntax = QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
        caseSensitivity = QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive
        regExp = QtCore.QRegExp(string_text, caseSensitivity, syntax)
        model.setFilterRegExp(regExp)

    def addMail(self, model, subject, sender, date):
        model.insertRow(0)
        model.setData(model.index(0, 0), subject)
        model.setData(model.index(0, 1), sender)
        model.setData(model.index(0, 2), date)

    def createMailModel(self):
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Subject")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Sender")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Date")

        self.addMail(self.model, "Happy New Year!", "Grace K. <grace@software-inc.com>",
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2006, 12, 31), QtCore.QTime(17, 3)))
        self.addMail(self.model, "Radically new concept", "Grace K. <grace@software-inc.com>",
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2006, 12, 22), QtCore.QTime(9, 44)))
        self.addMail(self.model, "Accounts", "pascale@nospam.com",
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2006, 12, 31), QtCore.QTime(12, 50)))
        self.addMail(self.model, "Expenses", "Joe Bloggs <joe@bloggs.com>",
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2006, 12, 25), QtCore.QTime(11, 39)))
        self.addMail(self.model, "Re: Expenses", "Andy <andy@nospam.com>",
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2007, 1, 2), QtCore.QTime(16, 5)))
        self.addMail(self.model, "Re: Accounts", "Joe Bloggs <joe@bloggs.com>",
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2007, 1, 3), QtCore.QTime(14, 18)))
        self.addMail(self.model, "Re: Accounts", "Andy <andy@nospam.com>",
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2007, 1, 3), QtCore.QTime(14, 26)))
        self.addMail(self.model, "Sports", "Linda Smith <linda.smith@nospam.com>",
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2007, 1, 5), QtCore.QTime(11, 33)))
        self.addMail(self.model, "AW: Sports", "Rolf Newschweinstein <rolfn@nospam.com>",
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2007, 1, 5), QtCore.QTime(12, 0)))
        self.addMail(self.model, "RE: Sports", "Petra Schmidt <petras@nospam.com>",
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2007, 1, 5), QtCore.QTime(12, 1)))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Window()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does it give the same thing when you move the setColumnHidden after the setModel ?

Comment: Just a comment: The given code is not minimal which might make solving the problem more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @Trilaroin: I think the given code is minimal. Don't think about the overwritten Model()-class. Just take a look in the window()-class. This clas is very minimal.

Comment: @Laurent G: I will try to move the setColumnHidden()-method, when I am back home again. Till later.